# Curve that is used as text guide for round text is open path. Is it problem for stocks?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path, stock-images

On my vector I created rounded text. For this I used Ellipse tool to create circle, the with scissors cut it in two halfs on diameter.

Then every half of circle was used as guide for text. It is invisible, but it is still detected as not closed path. Example of situation is shown on image below (path is actually invisible, I'm just using Outline). I can't remove this open path because in this case text will be removed as well. And I can't close it manually either.

Questions:

1. How do you think, can such path be a problem when image will be checked by stock editors?
2. If so - how to close this path correctly?

[image]
Thank you for help.

Comment: What "image check phase"? And if it's a guide can't you just remove it before production?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the situation. Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Guys, screen is added and phrase "image check phase" is clarified in question text

Comment: If the path is *not* needed to render art.. just remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't remove it - in the case rounded text is removed as well

Comment: If it's text on a path.. I don't think stock sites accept *live* text in files. You'll need to expand the art, in which case the path will no longer be necessary.

Comment: @Scott I checked it - when text is converted to outlines - this open path is removed automatically and everything is OK. Thank you once again